# check if there are same value in list python

Tags: python, arrays

For example, if passed the following:

```
a = ['a','a','z','d','j','w','w']
```

how do I check if there is 'a' and 'w' repeated more than once and got 'a' index 0 and 1, 'w' index 5 and 6?

Comment: Use `a.count('a')` and see if it is > 1.

Comment: ``collections.Counter(a)`` will give you length of repeated character

Comment: Apart from a missing attempt to solve it yourself, the problem is insufficiently described. Do you want to get the positions of all strings occuring more than once? Can all strings in the list be assumed to have length 1?

Comment: thanks got work with collections.Counter(a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a frequency list out of the original list and iterate over this to know the indices where the duplicate items exists:

```
# original list
a = ['a','a','z','d','j','w','w']

# list of frequency
list_count = [a.count(x) for x in a]

# print the frequency list
print('Frequency list: %s' % list_count)

# iterate over the frequency list and get the indices of the values greater than 1
for index, value in enumerate(list_count):
    if value > 1:
        print('Duplicate value found at index: %s which is %s' % (index, a[index]))
```